# Tensorflow Modify OpKernelConstruction Attributes

Tags: c++, tensorflow

In kernel operations, an OpKernelConstruction pointer is given to the OpKernel constructor, for [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/fifo_queue_op.cc#L44)

I would like to change some attributes in the context before passing it to the parent constructor.

For example, something like

```
explicit StreamQueueOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : 
    TypedQueueOp(private_modifying_method(context))
```

But it appears in the description of [OpKernelConstruction](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L213), that no modifying method exists. Is there a way to modify it?

EDIT:

I want to modify the attributes because I am attempting to make a FIFOQueue that pulls data from a database. I only want the user to have to specify the data stream id and then the queue would hit the database for the shape and type of the data. As such, I want to modify the context to add the shape and type info after I get it from the DB, but before I pass the context onto the base class. The base class makes use of shape and type, so I need to make sure it is in correspondence with the DB.

Comment: What do you mean? Most of the members in that class are non-const.

Comment: There is a publicly exposed Attribute accessor GetAttr but I don't see a public method that is for modifying the attributes in the Protobuf.

Comment: Oh, I don't think it's possible. `OpKernelConstruction::def_` is const. Could you elaborate a bit more on the use case?

Comment: You confirmed my fear. See edit

Comment: We can work with dynamic shapes, but type is tricky, because the choice of kernels etc downstream depends on type. Could you make an outside call to figure out the type a priori?

Comment: The problem is that I am not assembling my graph in Python. I am building it in JSON via Protobuf (see my other questions). I could make the call in Python and pass it to the C++, but it would seem to be the same. I would personally prefer TF to error out if the Type is messed up. Should I just do it from Python?

Comment: The op should error out if it's got the wrong type, if that's just an error you need, rather than dynamically switch what type it is.